# Why Hibernate saves BigDecimals with 0 after point?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have simple column:

```
@Column(name = "MYCOLUMN", precision = 19, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal myColumn;
```

And I want to save for example `new BigDecimal("1000000000000000000");`, but what I actually get is `1000000000000000000.00`, why Hibernate has such behavior? Can I change it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In you DB this would like to be stored as a double (mysql) and hence `scale = 2` is in fact scale 2

Answer (score 0):

Use this `scale = 0` and then you wont have a 0 after decimal.

```
 @Column(name = "MYCOLUMN", precision = 19, scale = 0)
 private BigDecimal myColumn;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the big integer you might handle in getter method without affecting DB model

```
public BigInteger getMycolumn(){ 
   return myColumn.toBigInteger()
}
```